# mysqldump avoid file creation if no results

Tags: mysql

I try to make a differential backup from last backup like this:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --replace --skip-comments --skip-triggers --hex-blob  
testdb mytable --where="last_backup > '$last_backup'" | gzip -c > backup_file.gz
```

All ok but if no changes from the last backup mysqldump get one empty file (only header and footer lines specific to mysql)

Is there a way to **avoid the creation of backup_file.gz if no changes?**

SOME LIKE:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE last_backup > '$last_backup') > 0) THEN 
mysqldump --no-create-info --replace --skip-comments --skip-triggers --hex-blob  
testdb mytable --where="last_backup > '$last_backup'" | gzip -c > backup_file.gz
```

Comment: No. Thank you ... the code above is part of my own backup tool (because I have sepecific case ... ) My problem is not how to make a backup ...  what I need is if no results no create file. I know also I can try first a mysql query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE last_backup > 'last_date_backup'` ... But I ask if that possible in command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved with this:

```
if [[ "$(mysql -sse 'USE my_bd; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE last_backup > '$last_backup'" -gt "0" ]]; then 
mysqldump --no-create-info --replace --skip-comments --skip-triggers --hex-blob  
testdb mytable --where="last_backup > '$last_backup'" | gzip -c > backup_file.gz 
fi
```

The mysqldump command must be in one line. I have splited to be more readable
But the If condition can be in multiple lines